# Common Lisp: How to create a concatenation-prefix macro, similar to '?

Tags: syntax, common-lisp, notation, prefix-operator

Common Lisp macros typically use included-prefix notation: (operator stuff...)

However, the special quote macro ' uses concatenated-prefix notation: operator stuff  , or alternatively operator(stuff).

I would like to create a custom macro in SBCL Common Lisp, let's call it !, that uses concatenation-prefix syntax to operate on a following list (or even atom), in a similar manner to ' .  So I could invoke it anywhere, e.g. (setq foo !(bar) ), without it being infixed in parentheses itself.

How can this be done?  What would the defmacro syntax look like?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways to do it.

The first, simple variant is suitable, if you need it only for a single or very limited number of cases and you're satisfied with using just a single symbol as a prefix (like `!` in the example case). You can create a read-macro, more specifically set a `macro-character` to substitute such operator for, say, addition:

```
(set-macro-character #\! (lambda (stream char)
                           (declare (ignore char))
                           (cons '+ (let ((next (read stream t nil t)))
                                 (if (consp next) next
                                     (list next)))))
CL-USER> !1
1
CL-USER> !(1 2)
3
```

The other, more complex and more flexible way is to define a macro, inside which apply a custom transformation, that will turn concatenated-prefix code into included-prefix. This trick uses the fact, that ordinary Lisp reader will read the in the same way both `foo(bar)` and `foo (bar)`, i.e. it will split them into 2 elements.

The simple version of such macro may look like this:

```
(defmacro with-prefix-syntax (&body body)
  `(progn ,@(loop :for tail :on body :while body
                  :collect (if (and (not (atom (second tail)))
                                    (fboundp (first tail)))
                               (prog1 (cons (first tail) (second tail)
                                 (setf tail (rest tail)))
                               (first tail)))))
```

It will transform only top-level forms:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(with-prefix-syntax
                           print(1)))
(PROGN (PRINT 1))
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(with-prefix-syntax
                           1))
(PROGN 1)
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(with-prefix-syntax
                           print(1)
                           2))
(PROGN (PRINT 1) 2)
```

But not work in the lower levels:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(with-prefix-syntax
                           print(1)
                           (+ print(2))))
(PROGN (PRINT 1) (+ PRINT (2)))
```

Though it's rather easy to make it recursively transform all the layers (which is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: I think you meant `(set-macro-character #\! ..` :)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting answer.  Will let this one sit for two weeks to see what else we might get...

Comment: So your second method essentially sets up a context, and then rewrites all the code inside it.  That's pretty good.  It does require looking at all the code inside the context twice, which can get compiled out for programs but will be slightly costly for run-time interpretation of large data, I suppose.  Still, that's the price you pay.  Pretty cool.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with read-macros, will have to look these up, this looks like closer to what I had in mind.  Does this hack only stand-alone atoms, or will hacking the reader affect all instances of the char?  What happens if I also have a function (not!ohno) with the hacked char in the middle--will it split this up into something weird?  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the reader-macro, it will trigger only for the forms, that start with `!`. Regarding the code-rewriting macro, I forgot to mention one restriction: it looses some dynamism of ordinary Lisp, as it checks, if the symbol is a function/macro at the time of macroexpansion. Although, that should be a minor inconvenience, which doesn't effect most use-cases. Also, to clarify, it requires only one pass over the input code.